# How do you set a variable equal to the window URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check how many slashes the window URL contains.

```
//var url = "www.myurl.com/segment1/segment2segment3";
var url = windowURL.indexOf.href;
var segment = url.split("/").length - 1 - (url.indexOf("http://")==-1?0:2);
alert(segment);
```

This gives errors of saying windowURL is not defined.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit:
I'm trying this now, which retrieves the URL but gives the wrong number of slashes, given that **I thought the code below omitted the https:// slashes.** Maybe I'm wrong? I want it to omit those...

```
var url = window.location.href;
alert(url);
var segment = url.split("/").length - 1 - (url.indexOf("http://")==-1?0:2);
alert(segment);
```

Comment: Your edited code will work if you replace the `http` in your sentinel of indexOf with `https` since that seems to be your goal in bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.match()`

`.match()` returns `null` if there is no match.

```js
var windowURL = "http://www.myurl.com/segment1/segment2segment3";
var count = windowURL.match(/\//g).length - 
(windowURL.indexOf("http://")==-1?0:2);
console.log(count);
```

Comment: Thanks, the match method is way cleaner! Is there a way to make it omit the https:// slashes? Maybe it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to read the current URL of the page?
`window.location.href`

```js
var url = window.location.href;
var segments = url.split("/");
console.log(url, segments);
```

Comment: Why there is extra `1` I don't understand ?